# Sort the order of fasta sequence using python

Tags: python, fasta

I have a fasta file (consists of >header and sequence lines) as below:

myfasta

```
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch16_153_209
AACCCTAACCCTAACCCTTGATTGATTGATTGATTGATTGAT
TGATTGATGAAATTATAGTCTCCGTAAAGCAAATAAAGCATT
TAGTAAACGTTGAAGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAATACAAAAAGG
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch16_153_209
AACCCTAACCCTAACCCTTGATTGATTGATTGATTGATTGAT
TAGTAAACGTTGAAGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAATACAAAAAGG
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch14_442_1137
TGTCAATTCGATCTAGTATT
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch12_1831_180
AGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAAT
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch1_1831_180
AGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAATAGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAAT
AGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAATAGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAAT
```

I want to print this file in a defined order (starting with Ch1 to Ch16) and get the result as below:

```
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch1_1831_180
AGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAATAGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAAT
AGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAATAGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAAT
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch12_1831_180
AGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAAT
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch14_442_1137
TGTCAATTCGATCTAGTATT
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch16_153_209
AACCCTAACCCTAACCCTTGATTGATTGATTGATTGATTGAT
TAGTAAACGTTGAAGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAATACAAAAAGG
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch16_153_209
AACCCTAACCCTAACCCTTGATTGATTGATTGATTGATTGAT
TGATTGATGAAATTATAGTCTCCGTAAAGCAAATAAAGCATT
TAGTAAACGTTGAAGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAATACAAAAAGG
```

I tried to write this code, but I am still getting the same order as my input file in my `result.fasta`. Any help would be appreciated in fixing my code. Thanks!

Code: python code.py myfasta.fasta  >> result.fasta

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import pathlib

myfasta = sys.argv[1]
fasta = open(myfasta)

#types = ['S.sclerotiorum_Ch16_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch15_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch14_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch13_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch12_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch11_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch10_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch9_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch8_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch7_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch6_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch5_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch4_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch3_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch2_', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch1_']

types = ['S.sclerotiorum_Ch1', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch2', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch3', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch4', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch5', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch6', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch7', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch8', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch9', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch10', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch11', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch12', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch13', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch14', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch15', 'S.sclerotiorum_Ch16']




for type in range(len(types)):
    flag = False
    fasta = open(myfasta)
    for line in fasta:
        if line.startswith('>') and types[type] in line:
            flag = True
        elif line.startswith('>'):
          flag = False
        if flag:
            #grabbed = line.strip()
            #newfasta.writelines(grabbed + "\n")
            print(line.strip())

fasta.close
```

Comment: you'd be better off by reading the file only once and put the lines in an indexed dict. Then print keys & values in the given order

Comment: You should have a look at regex (`re` module).

Comment: oh, but you have duplicate keys... argh

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` with a pattern that matches a line followed by lines that start with a non-`>` character and also groups the number after `Ch`, use `sorted` to sort the matches according to the number, and use `str.join` to join the sorted substrings back to a string:

```
import re
''.join(s for s, _ in sorted(re.findall(r'(.*_Ch(\d+)_.*\n(?:[^>].*\n)*)', f), key=lambda t: int(t[1])))
```

Given your input string stored in `f` (you should read the entire file into this variable first), this returns:

```
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch1_1831_180
AGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAATAGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAAT
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch12_1831_180
AGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAAT
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch14_442_1137
TGTCAATTCGATCTAGTATT
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch16_153_209
AACCCTAACCCTAACCCTTGATTGATTGATTGATTGATTGAT
TGATTGATGAAATTATAGTCTCCGTAAAGCAAATAAAGCATT
TAGTAAACGTTGAAGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAATACAAAAAGG
>S.sclerotiorum_Ch16_153_209
AACCCTAACCCTAACCCTTGATTGATTGATTGATTGATTGAT
TAGTAAACGTTGAAGAGCTAGAAAAGCTTTAATACAAAAAGG
```